# How to call WCF service application from local html file?

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to call a WCF service hosted in localhost from a file that is in a directory of our computer (like "C:\Test\") ?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, by ajax to a remote WCF service.

Otherwise, no, the file would need to be 'processed' by a webserver in order to connect to the service, such as running an .aspx page from IIS.